# EditorFor with the same model type twice

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, mvc-editor-templates

I'm dealing with this problem.

I'm using `EditorFor` for a model which is an abstract class.

```
@model Contoso.Core.Base.Question

@Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Id)
@Html.Hidden("ModelType", Model.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName)

@Html.EditorFor(model => Model, Contoso.Core.QuestionRepositoryManager.GetQuestionView(Model))
```

As you can above, later invoke a concrete editor for the model and what does MVC is only render the first one (I mean, print hidden input fields "Id and ModelType", but not for the inputs in the concrete `EditorFor`).

How can I do to print these two `EditorFor`? I was reading about using `PartialView`, but I don't like this idea because I don't know how to bind these properties in the `POST Method`.

**UPDATE:**

1. I'm not sure if do I have to modify the prefixHtml to fix this?

   ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = ...
2. It renders the second template because if I change to `Editor` instead of `EditorFor`

   @Html.Editor("abc", Contoso.Core.QuestionRepositoryManager.GetQuestionView(Model))

Comment: What exactly is "GetQuestionView()" and what does it return?  Are you sure it's doing what you think it's doing?

Comment: It's a function which returns a templateName for the concrete model. Yes, returns the value string correctly

Comment: Without more information, there's little we can do.  You need to provide your editor template (it is in the EditorTemplates folder, right?), you need to provide the model...

Comment: All right, give me some minutes to added

Comment: @MystereMan I realized of something, if I replace in the second one: EditorFor to Editor, it works!! `@Html.Editor("abc", Contoso.Core.QuestionRepositoryManager.GetQuestionView(Model))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem here is that the compiler is choosing the wrong overload.  If you look at the overloads of EditorFor, you see there are two that take two parameters:

```
public static MvcHtmlString EditorFor<TModel, TValue>(
this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,
Object additionalViewData
)
```

and

```
public static MvcHtmlString EditorFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,
    string templateName
)
```

You could try this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => Model, 
     Contoso.Core.QuestionRepositoryManager.GetQuestionView(Model) as string)
```

or you could do this:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => Model, 
     Contoso.Core.QuestionRepositoryManager.GetQuestionView(Model), null)
```

There are also two constructors that take 3 arguments, but either of them, the second argument is always the template name, so by passing null it really doesn't matter which is chosen.

The problem may also be that `GetQuestionView()` returns an object instead of a string, and that is why it's choosing the wrong constructor, making sure the return type of `GetQuestionView()` is string may also fix it.  Although I'm not sure why it works with Editor, since the same problem would exist there as the constructors are pretty analogous.